# Chnges with regard to firebase v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My friend wrote this code last year, Now that firebase v9 has some syntax changes, its not working anymore. What changes should i make -

```
useEffect(() => {
    const colRef = collection(db, 'movies',doc(id)) 
    colRef.doc(id)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            setDetailData(doc.data());
        } else {
            console.log("No such document in firebase ");
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting the document: ",error);
    });
}, [id]);
```

The problem is in the colRef.doc(id) section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the solution in the documentation in the  ["Get a document"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) section (Tab "Web version 9").

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";


useEffect(() => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "movies", id);

    getDoc(docRef)
        .then((doc) => {
            if (doc.exists()) {
                setDetailData(doc.data());
            } else {
                console.log("No such document in firebase ");
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting the document: ", error);
        });
}, [id]);
```

Comment: Now the error says .get() is not a function

Comment: My mistake, I had forgotten to remove one line. It should be ok now.